# Send an automated email to a list of people when Value of J = false

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I have used in the past to send out an automated email to a list of folks and it's worked beautifully.  I'd like to have the script check to see if there are values in the row first and if there are, check to see if the value in J = false, before sending the email to the list.

Link to the sheet [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PCWZJmR16bpCleBMA88IOLPIPNlzurH_pkbaG6wdtKM/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I'm using for the timed send:

```
//Sends email to Purchasing Dept at setup trigger desired time
function sendEmailsToPurchasing() { // Get the sheet where the data is, in sheet 'email list'
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("email list") 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process since there is a header row 
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process is set by a formula which counts rows 
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B where the emails and messages are 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range to input into the mailing system 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  // This processes the emails you want to send 
  for (i in data) { 
    var row = data[i]; var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column is the email address 
    var message = row[1] + "\n\n**Please do not respond to this email as it is automatically generated by an account that is not checked.**\n\nPlease check the Procurement Issues to Resolve Google Sheet for new or unresolved entries"; // Second and third columns are the message 
    var subject = "Procurement Issues Update"; // This is the subject of the email 
  // This parses the data for the email to send 
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmailsToPurchasing() { 
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("email list") 
  var sr=2;
  var numRows=sh.getRange(1,5).getValue();
  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,numRows,sh.getLastColumn()) 
  var data=rg.getValues(); 
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
    var row=data[i]; 
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var message = row[1] + "\n\n**Please do not respond to this email as it is automatically generated by an account that is not checked.**\n\nPlease check the Procurement Issues to Resolve Google Sheet for new or unresolved entries";
    var subject = "Procurement Issues Update"; 
    if(!row[9]) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Cooper, thank you.  This worked.  As I am trying to get better at js, would you mind explaining the few differences that I see between our code?  from what I can tell, you're having the script look for the last row with data 'code' var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,numRows,sh.getLastColumn()) 'code' and if the last row is 9 or Column J hen send the email 'code' if(!row[9]) 'code' but I'm confused as to how the if statement works.

Comment: If(!row[9]) is just asking the question is column 10 false and if it is then send email